# Access VBA: Opening the recordset asks for 4 parameters

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()

    ' This section deals with grabbing the 3 calculations from qry_LiveOEE
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    'Open a dynaset-type Recordset using a saved query
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("qry_LiveOEE", dbOpenDynaset)

    rst.MoveFirst
    numfg_posted = rst!SumOfqty_complete
    numOEE = rst!OEE
    numpp_lhr = rst!ACT_PPLHR

    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
```

I get an error saying `Too few parameters. Expected 4.` This query has 5 things in the ***criteria*** section (design view), so why is it saying I need 4 parameters?

The 5 things in the criteria section (all under different fields) are:

1. input from a form
2. input from a form
3. Switch statement based on current time
4. Date()
5. Is Not Null

Comment: maybe is rst.OpenRecordset()

Comment: check out this link for more info :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034959/open-recordset-in-access-2003-2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not tested) update to the code:

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()

    ' This section deals with grabbing the 3 calculations from qry_LiveOEE
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qdf AS DAO.QueryDef
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_LiveOEE")
    For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
        prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
    Next prm
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

    rst.MoveFirst
    numfg_posted = rst!SumOfqty_complete
    numOEE = rst!OEE
    numpp_lhr = rst!ACT_PPLHR

    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
```

Make sure all the values in the parameters are available - i.e. the form is open.

Comment: @whatin1992: or see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32118340/3820271 if you need this regularly.

Comment: Yep, pulled it from my own function which does something similar (but also exports to Excel) - one change I'd make to the link is that the parameters are part of a collection so can use a `For...Each` construct rather than a `For...Next`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: Heh, true. I think that function dates back to Access 2.0 when there was no `For Each`. :) -- Edited the answer.